# Messaging schema between users

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-schema

There are users. Each user can have multiple properties. Users can initiate conversation with the owner of the property from property's page, if it isn't their own property.

I have following tables:

User (table)

```
id integer
username varchar
....
```

Property (table)

```
id integer
user_id integer
....
```

Message (table)

```
 id integer
 sender integer fk
 receiver integer fk
 property_id integer fk
 message varchar
 created_at timestamp
```

I've come up with above mentioned `message` table to store conversations. When user logs in, he/she can see all conversations (only last message from each conversation) and can further expand to see conversation fully.

So to get all conversations for the current user I must select everything from `message` table where `sender` or `receiver` is current user and group them by `property_id` as I need conversations separated by `property_id`.

For example 2 users can have 2 separate conversations regarding each property and practically they don't need to even know that they're speaking to the same person in each case. All that matters is that conversation is about property.

I've come up with following SQL (mysql) to fetch all conversations for the current user, but I don't think it is the optimal way and I don't think that this approach will scale good (from the performance point of view).

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `message`
WHERE `id` IN
  (SELECT MAX(`id`)
  FROM `message`
  WHERE (`sender` = @current_user OR `receiver` = @current_user)
  GROUP BY CONCAT((`sender`+`receiver`), `property_id`))
```

Any suggestions to do this better?

P.S. Without adding another table to equation and suggestion can be based on the fact that `property_id` always belongs to one distinct user (though I couldn't come up with the way to use it).

**Edit 1**
Is `MAX(id)` reliable here? Anyway to order by `created_at` to get the latest message for each conversation?

**Edit 2:** Take into account that conversation is unique based on `sender`, `receiver` and `property_id` having `sender` or `receiver` being the current user.

Comment: Are you really looking for an integer (id) in a timestamp (MAX(`created_at`))?

Comment: @jarlh My fault, I edited my question to reflect what I need. Also corrected query.